Error - undefined module "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+" when building aosp bundled with custom system app
Building aosp for target 'lunch sdk_phone_x86_64'
I have included a custom system app which uses tensorflow hence within the Android.bp this is the dependency declaration.
static_libs: [
        "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
    "com.google.android.material_material"

        ], 

This is the error upon running the make command
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename
 "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top 
"$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja 
--globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_pat
hs/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_
env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp

error: packages/apps/PureVision/Android.bp:5:1: "PureVision" depends on undefine
d module "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+"
08:16:29 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

I have tried using a different different versions of tensorflow with no success
Any help/guidance is appreciated

Library references in AOSP are not like library references in gradle files when developing plain Android apps.
In particular org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+ looks like a maven-style reference that when used with gradle downloads the library at build time. AOSP does not support maven-style dynamic downloading of libraries and has a build system not based on gradle. In AOSP 100% of code and libraries must already be available locally and must have an Android.bp or Android.mk specific to AOSP for every app and library.
Two main choices:

If you don't actually need to access hidden APIs just develop a regular android app in Android Studio and then include the pre-built unsigned APK in AOSP How to Add Pre-built App (System App) in AOSP source code
It does appear tensorflow lite is already checked in to AOSP (hopefully it is a version that works for you), the java library has the name tensorflowlite_java, see https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/024ba53c0ef502fbd701e14f4f80e1d2106f7f59:external/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/java/Android.bp

